# Sending all network traffic from a VM?

Tags: networking, virtualbox

One VM is set the network card as internal in Vbox.

I'm trying to send all it's network traffic to another VM with same internal card, transparently. Can `iptables` help?

Here is the internal network setup:

```
VBoxManage dhcpserver add --netname testlab --ip 10.10.10.1 --netmask 255.255.255.0 --lowerip 10.10.10.2 --upperip 10.10.10.12 --enable
```

Comment: The default route of the source VM should point to the IP of the target VM. It depends on your goals, if it is okay. If you want to provide some unavoidable box for the secondary VM, then it would be better to do it on a way, where the VM can't change it on any method (i.e. better to create an additional internal network for the task: the testlab VM would exist only on this, while your gateway-VM would exist on both).

Comment: The dhcp server of the virtualbox is not a very well configurable one, you may get what you want or you may not. I don't know. If it is not a massive install, then it may be simpler to hardwire the network settings in the testlab VM. And merry christmas :-)